# Magento: Where is Url rewrite index process logic stored?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, indexing

I need to make product urls like this "specials/product-url-key.html" . I've found that the easiest way to do it is to simply add "specials/" at the begining of every product url rewrite in the core_url_rewrite table, request path field.

I would like to make change to the indexer process as well, so the changes will stay when its rerun, but I don't know where it is?

My Include category in product URL option is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

Read more here: http://www.magento-tutorial.net/how-does-magento-url-rewriting-work/

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help me with my case :( I can't change anything in there without braking the other rewrites.

Comment: But you can make a module. Each magento module can have its own rewrites.